# How can I disable errors by directory?

Tags: php, error-handling

We are writing php apps based on a library that has a lot of Notices and Strict Standard Warnings.

We would like to develop our applications with full error reporting. We can't right now because the lib is causing to many errors. We would like to suppress all errors from this lib and only show those of our apps on our development machines.

With the help of set_error_handler function I could already implement that.

Is there any other way to do this maybe on a php.ini or vhost level?

Answer (score 3):

For Apache:
add to .htaccess file (or in vhost configuration):

```
php_value error_reporting 1
```

But this separation can by used only when Apache parses URL.
Let you have this folders:

`/www/dir/

/models/

/lib/`

And .htaccess placed in `/www/dir/` and in `lib`.

If you will call URL `example.com/dir`, then .htaccess will be parsed by Apache and setting will be set.
But in case of `'include /lib/some.php'` - Apache will not parse `lib` and `.htaccess` will not give any effect.

Comment: This would be rather useless, since warnings are occurring in libraries (that are included) and `.htaccess` setting refers only to files opened directly in given directory.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: `.htaccess`-files are evaluated by the apache for every request, that matches a file in the given directory. Once its evaluated, it doesn't care which other files are included.

Comment: @KingCrunch : `Once its evaluated, it doesn't care which other files are included` - That's exactly what I meant. And since requests should never reach directory with libraries (often they are outside DocumentRoot) putting .htaccess there (or setting rules for vhost) would not affect php configuration

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Filtering errors with custom function and `set_error_handler` by checking path of file that caused an error is the best you can do.

Other solutions that might be better, but only under some conditions:

- newer version of the library (if exists and have same functionality)
- fix problems in this library yourself (if license allows it)
- disabling error reporting before including libraries and enabling it after (if most errors occurs during inclusion not actual usage)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's possible to prepend scripts: php_value auto_prepend_file prepend.php

So I can prepend a script which uses my own error_handler. This way I can trigger this via vhost/php.ini directive.

Thanks for all the input.